# Finding Binary to C/C++ link

Tags: c++, c, build, makefile

Ours is a complex build process. We have huge number of binaries built. I wanted to get information regarding binary(exe, dll, so) to source code (C, C++) file link. I wanted to know by which C, C++ files or lib files is the binary built. This is to do a separate analysis on our code base. Ours is a make build file system to build our binaries. I wanted to know if there exists a technique or tool to extract this information. My search on the site reached scan-build which runs the static analysis tool before the files are built.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
GreyCells

Comment: Your question title should be more clear. And your question is not clear to me. Do you want to know where is the source file by working with binary?

Comment: What keeps you from logging and analysing the output of the build process?

Comment: Which build tools do you use?

Comment: A debug build should incorporate source information in to the binaries created.

Comment: @amol chavan "so" is not binary file, it indicates library file

Comment: @Pawan: Libraries may very well be considered binaries. They might not be considered executables however.

Comment: @thanks alk for clarification. I agree binary files can be of any type.

Answer (score 1):

For lib files associated with a particular binary you can use `ldd` command, assuming you are using linux systems.

For c/c++ files, you can try `strings` command in linux with combination of `grep` command e.g. `strings binary | grep "\.c"` 
This command gave me list of cpp file which is used for creating binary file. I hope this is what you were looking for.

The same command can be used with library (so file) to find C/C++ associated with it.

Comment: This does not link down to source-file level.

Comment: Debug info (including source file along with pathes) might only be available in special builds. Those typically do not go into production.

Comment: Thanks all, especially Pawan. I found the strings command useful, I also found readelf, objdump and nm commands on linux. Also there are a few tools like objconvert on windows also. This solves my problem

Comment: thanx @AmolChavan for feedback :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the non-standard but widely supported `#ident` directive to add an identification string. This is typically used to add version information or copyright strings to the binary, but you can also use it to note which source files went into the binary. In each source file, place this line:

```
#ident __FILE__
```

to make the file name of each source file appear in the binary. On ELF targets, the argument to `#ident` is placed in the `.comment` section, this might be different on other targets but generally the information ends up in the binary.

Comment: Thanks, but that not an option to add any thing in sources. All I have is release binaries to play with. I could extract it with readelf on linux

Comment: @AmolChavan If you only have binaries, you have no chance to get information about the corresponding source files. This kind of information is usually not stored in the binary, unless you explicity do so in the source file.